# Windows fatal exception: code 0xc0000374 while tunning Keras hyperparameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, fatal-error

I have been trying to tune my hyperparameters using [KerasTuner](https://keras.io/keras_tuner/). But at some epoch in the 11th search trial, this error happened:

```
Windows fatal exception: code 0xc0000374


Main thread:
Current thread 0x000060f0 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\ldsp_\miniconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_dataset_ops.py", line 3314 in make_iterator
  File "C:\Users\ldsp_\miniconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py", line 787 in _create_iterator
  File "C:\Users\ldsp_\miniconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py", line 755 in __init__
  File "C:\Users\ldsp_\miniconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py", line 486 in __iter__
  File "C:\Users\ldsp_\miniconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1191 in enumerate_epochs
  File "C:\Users\ldsp_\miniconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1710 in evaluate
  File "C:\Users\ldsp_\miniconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64 in error_handler
  File "C:\Users\ldsp_\miniconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1420 in fit
  File "C:\Users\ldsp_\miniconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64 in error_handler
  File "C:\Users\ldsp_\miniconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\src\engine\hypermodel.py", line 149 in fit
  File "C:\Users\ldsp_\miniconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\src\engine\tuner.py", line 233 in _build_and_fit_model
  File "C:\Users\ldsp_\miniconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\src\engine\tuner.py", line 314 in run_trial
  File "C:\Users\ldsp_\miniconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\src\engine\base_tuner.py", line 238 in _run_and_update_trial
  File "C:\Users\ldsp_\miniconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\src\engine\base_tuner.py", line 273 in _try_run_and_update_trial
  File "C:\Users\ldsp_\miniconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\src\engine\base_tuner.py", line 233 in search
  File "C:\Users\ldsp_\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_37800\4114843125.py", line 166 in <module>
```

After some research, I found that this is related to memory problems (not sure, correct me if I am wrong).

I am using `tensorflow` `2.8.0`, `keras` `2.8.0` and `keras-tuner` `1.4.6`.

Here is the code:

```
import time
import keras_tuner
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import InputLayer
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.losses import SparseCategoricalCrossentropy
from keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

percentuais_amostras = [0.5]

rede = 'LSTM'
dataset = 'D4'
modelo = 'M5_GS'
for perc_amostras in percentuais_amostras:
    df = pd.read_csv(f'C:/Users/ldsp_/miniconda3/envs/tf-gpu/Irish/Dataset_{dataset}/Dataset_{dataset}_{perc_amostras}.txt', sep=' ')
    x = df.iloc[:, :-1].values
    y = df['FLAG'].values
    del df
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
    del x, y
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1)

    # %% LSTM

    def criar_modelo(hp):
        classifier_LSTM = Sequential(name=f'{rede}_{modelo}_{perc_amostras}')
        classifier_LSTM.add(InputLayer((x_train.shape[1], 1), name='Camada_Entrada'))
        classifier_LSTM.add(LSTM(hp.Int('first_lstm', min_value=32, max_value=64, step=32),
                                     return_sequences=True, name='1_Camada_LSTM'))
        classifier_LSTM.add(LSTM(hp.Int('last_lstm', min_value=32, max_value=64, step=32),
                                     return_sequences=False, name='2_Camada_LSTM'))
        for k in range(hp.Int("num_layers", 1, 2)):
            classifier_LSTM.add(Dense(units=hp.Int(f'units_{k}',
                                                   min_value=2 * len(np.unique(y_train)),
                                                   max_value=3 * len(np.unique(y_train)),
                                                   step=len(np.unique(y_train))),
                                            activation='relu', 
                                            name=f'{k}_dense'))
        if hp.Boolean("dropout"):
            classifier_LSTM.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
        classifier_LSTM.add(Dense(units=len(np.unique(y_train)),
                            activation='softmax',
                            name='Camada_Saida'))
        classifier_LSTM.compile(optimizer='adam',
                          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                          metrics=['accuracy'])
        return classifier_LSTM

    tuner = keras_tuner.GridSearch(
        hypermodel=criar_modelo,
        objective='val_loss',
        max_trials=33,
        executions_per_trial=1,
        overwrite=True,
        directory=f'C:/Users/ldsp_/miniconda3/envs/tf-gpu/Irish/{rede}/Resultados {rede}_{modelo}/',
        project_name='tuning')
    print(tuner.search_space_summary())

# %% Callbacks

    earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                              min_delta=1e-4,
                              patience=50,
                              verbose=1,
                              mode='min',
                              restore_best_weights=True)
    cb = [earlystop]
    val_size = 0.2
    tuner.search(x_train,
                 y_train,
                 batch_size=256,
                 epochs=300,
                 callbacks=cb,
                 validation_split=val_size,
                 shuffle=True)

    # %% Results

    trials = tuner.oracle.get_best_trials(num_trials=5)
    HP_list = []
    for trial in trials:
        hyperparameters_config = trial.hyperparameters.get_config()["values"]
        hyperparameters_config.update({"val_loss": trial.score})
        HP_list.append(hyperparameters_config)
    HP_df = pd.DataFrame(HP_list)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'C:/Users/ldsp_/miniconda3/envs/tf-gpu/Irish/{rede}/Resultados {rede}_{modelo}/Results_GS_{perc_amostras}.xlsx',
                            engine='xlsxwriter')
    HP_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Results')
    writer._save()
```